# No plugin updates after moving wp-config.php above root map

Tags: plugins, updates, wp-config

After moving **wp-config.php** to a higher map then the root I get this **error message** when an **update** is started of **a plugin**.

Everything is working properly on the site only updates generates now errors,

How can I solve this so updating still runs without errors and without to move "wp-config.php" to root map back?

> Warning: unlink(/home/debxxx/security/domain/wp-content/uploads/updraftplus.1.12.25-YS3ytg.tmp): No such file or directory in /home/deb9xxx/domains/domain.com/public_html/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 505
>
> An error occurred while updating UpdraftPlus - Backup/Restore: Download failed. Destination directory for file streaming does not exist or is not writable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess ABSPATH defined in wp-config.php file now pointing not to root directory and that plugin trying to use this

Comment: ABSPATH  = /home/deb3456n2/domains/domain.com/public_html/aff/ and that is the root of the domain. So this is good. I have echo both wp_config.php files: 1: the root and 2: the file in the securitymap/ Boith with same result. ABSPATH = correct

Comment: Yep, I was wrong! ABSPATH defined earlier than wp-config

Comment: Still fithing with this problem how to solve this.